# Load device photos inside app like new google+

Tags: android, photo-gallery

I know how to pick an image from the gallery by using an Intent.
I want to load some images from my device on the bottom of the screen, like the new google+ app does when you hit new post.

[image: google+ screenshot]

Comment: A screenshot of the g+ feature that you're requesting would be helpful.

Comment: @Bolza screen shot added